# How to find $N-60$ when it is based on the sum of its prime divisors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, divisibility, number-systems

The problem is as follows:

> A certain number coincides with the sum of the prime positive divisors
> of the number of zeros in which the product of the first $784$
> integers ends positive, when expressed in base $15$ (pentadecimal).
> Find the number minus $60$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{33}\\
2.&\textrm{39}\\
3.&\textrm{30}\\
4.&\textrm{28}\\
\end{array}$

The official method of solution according to my book is as follows:

$784!=a(15)^n$

Then it goes to say that

$n=194=2\times 97$

to finally say that:

Then it declares that $2+97=99$
and finally saying this:

$99-60=39$

declaring that the official answer is $39$.

But that's my problem with this explanation. **How does it get the number from that factorial?**

The number it seems way to big to be computed by hand needless to say that from the sole equation of

$784!=a(15)^n$

it doesn't say what is $a$ or what is $n$? What does this has to do with pentadecimal base?. I don't get it.

Can someone explain me what is intended in this question and a **better argument of justification** in other words a **better solution method** which implies not fancy calculations or too encyclopedical in nature?

This request is based that my knowledge on the subject is somewhat limited so *I need all the steps necessary so I can understand.*

How can this problematic number be found?. This problem belongs to a section in my book about the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) although I don't see it in any way how could this be applied in this peculiar scenario.

Can someone help me here with an easy to follow and understand method of solution?

Comment: Using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), $n=\lfloor\frac {784}5\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{784}{25}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{784}{125}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{784}{625}\rfloor$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of zeros $n$ with which the product of the first 784 integers ends,

when expressed in base $15$ (pentadecimal), we need to find the highest power of $15$ dividing $784!.$

$15=3\times5$, so $n$ is also the highest power of $5$ dividing $784!$.

That can be obtained using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula):

$n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{784}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\dfrac{784}{25}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\dfrac{784}{125}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\dfrac{784}{625}\right\rfloor=156+31+6+1=194.$

Comment: I get the idea that you can see the number of zeros in powers ten. But in powers of $15$ does this happen?. I mean in pentadecimal base. **Why did you used $5$ but not $3$?** I am stuck on **why** did you stopped on $625$ in the denominator in Legendre's formula? is this a condition that you must stop in a number below the numerator to get the quotient for the floor function?. It seems that is chosen this way because you stop before getting the closest number to the numerator hence the unity. Is this assumption correct?.

Comment: The pentadecimal expression ends with $n$ zeroes iff $15^n$ divides the number and no higher power of $15$ does; to get divisibility by $15$ we need divisibility by $3$ and $5$, and there are more powers of $3$ than of $5$ in $784!$;  I stopped at $625$ because higher terms such as $\left\lfloor\frac{784}{3125}\right\rfloor$ are zero because $784<3125$

Comment: Let's use a small number to see a pentadecimal expression ends with zero. How would that be?. I kmean 594 in base 15 is 297 but it doesn't end with zeros. What I'm not getting?. How did you know beforehand that 784! has more powers of 3 than 5?. So is this the reason, just find which power sppears often?. I'm confused. Can you explain this better please? I'm confused **about the zeros**, **where are those zeros?** please explain this. I'm stuck.

Comment: For example $1200_{15}=1\times15^3+2\times15^2$ is divisible by $15^2$.  If you use Legendre's formula for $p=3$, you'll see there are more powers of $3$ than of $5$ in $784!$

Comment: So this number of zeros arise from the fact that the *problem indicates, the most numbers of zeros possible in the pentadecimal base*. **Is this correct?.** Thus this will be disible by $15^n$. Because 784! has more powers of $3$ than of $5$. **The limit or constrain** will be given by the power which appears the less in order to guarantee it will be divisible by $15$.

Comment: Because if we put together all the multiples of 3's in one end and the multiples of 5's in the other end, at some point we're running out of 5's in order to complete the 15. Is this a correct logic for the zeros in base 15 and the use of 5?. I'm sorry but I'm slow at catching up these ideas.

Comment: Assuming this part is correct. The whole thing was to obtain the prime factorization of the number of zeros. Am I finally right?.

Answer (score 0):

$784!$ has $1931$ decimal digits. The last $194$ are zero because of the $194$ factors $5$ in its factorization.

$194$ factors $=5$ are given by all multiples of $5$ which are $156=784$ divided by $5$.

Plus $5^2$ and its $31$ multiples $$25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,\\450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,775$$

$5^3$ and its $6$ multiples $$125,250,375,500,625,750$$

and $5^4=625$. Finally $156+31+6+1=194$

Therefore the factorization of $784!$ goes as:
$$784!=2^{781}\cdot 3^{390}\cdot 5^{194}\cdot\ldots$$
Prime factors of $194$ are $194=2\cdot 97$ and $2+97=99$.

So the answer is $99-60=39$

Comment: How did you obtained that the number of decimal digits from 784! is 1931? Please explain this part. I don't know why did you say that the last 194 are zero because of the 194 factors of 5. I don't understand this part you mentioned. The rest I'm lost. I don't know why you began stating the multiples of $5^2$ and $5^3$? are these multiples of 784!? is this because at some point we have $...5\times 4\times 3 \times 2 \times 1$? Please explain this part, because I'm confused.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The number of decimal digits of $N$ is $\log_{10}N$ rounded to the next integer